# How do I create a persistent USB 2.0 thumb drive install of Ubuntu in a Windows environment?

Tags: 10.04, boot, usb

I would like to turn this 32GB USB 2.0 flash drive into a 32 GB partition with Ubuntu installed on it which I can boot and read/write persist as any normal hard drive install would be expected to do. The trick is that I don't want to have to install Ubuntu to create this thing. Can I create it from a live boot of a CD? If so, I'll take the challenge to the next level by saying I'd like to avoid that as well. There has to be a way to create it from Windows to USB right? (I have ISO of 10.4)

Answer (score 3):

[UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is what you want. Runs on Windows and Linux and creates bootable flash drives from ISO images, 10.04 included. However, the default setup does *not* use persistent space, so changes made will be lost on shutdown. An appropriate way to work around this is to follow [these instructions](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/diskimg/readme.txt).

I believe you may be able to add `persistent` to the boot options alone, but I haven't tested this and the other method is what seems to work for most.

Comment: cool but the biggest .zip file available for the instructions provided is a 512mb.zip, I was hoping to have all 32GB of the USB drive be read/writable, or maybe I'm confused?

Comment: after some more digging I found this: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/ but it seems to indicate the biggest amount of space I could use would be 4GB, unless, again, I am misunderstanding this but I think the size of the casper-rw file is the amount of persistent space I will be given, right?

Comment: ooh, also found this: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ maybe this will do the trick, it's pretty current as of this month

Answer (score 1):

+1 to PenDriveLinux. They've been working on this for a while, they have half a dozen solutions. I've personally used one or two from a windows install (within a Ubuntu-hosted Virtual machine!) and works great.

Answer (score 0):

Following creates persistence partitions of any size:

Boot Live CD.

Plug in flash drive.

Start Partition Editor

Create 1GB+ FAT32 partition, (on the left side of the bar). (larger size is optional)

Create a 4GB+ ext2 partition to the right of this, labeled it "casper-rw". (ext3 and ext4 also work).

Create another ext2 partition in the remaining space and label it "home-rw". (optional, creates a separate home partition)

Close Partition Editor.

Un-mount and re-mount flash drive.

Start "Create a live usb startup disk", (usb-creator).

Select "Discard on shutdown".

Press "Make Startup Disk.

When usb-creator finishes, run "gksu nautilus"

Select disk / syslinux / text.cfg and add "persistent" as shown below:

append  noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz quiet splash --

Shutdown, remove CD, reboot.

You might like to make the first, (Fat32), partition larger as it is the only one a Windows machine can see.